# Slide div on and off the page on scroll without interrupting the animation when the user continues to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to smoothly slide a div on and off the page (left to right) using jQuery only. I have accomplished the task, however if you continue to scroll up or down while the animation is still going, it will interrupt it in the middle of the action causing it to hesitate. I've run into this issue before and could never figure it out without using a plugin of some sort.

I know how to accomplish this with CSS transitions, jQuery UI, greensock, etc., but I am curious if there is a way to prevent that interruption with jQuery only. I am open to a pure JavaScript solution (no jQuery) as well if there is one.

My code:

```
var amountScrolled = 50;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled) {
        $('#slide').stop().animate({marginLeft:"0px"}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#slide').stop().animate({marginLeft: "-400px"}, 500);
    }
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Hysteresis/hg9cvxop/6/

Comment: ( jQuery is JavaScript )

Comment: It's twitching because every time you scroll, the `$(window).scroll(function(){` is exectuted. I would get the scroll check function to fire another function which launches the animation, UNLESS it's already running.

Comment: why use jQuery when CSS and those other 3rd party libraries provide a good way to do it?

Comment: @CayceK that's like saying why cook your own Chicken when you can go to KFC...

Comment: @JoshStevenson no ... it is like saying [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)... it has been done a hundred times over. and in better ways. This is not the best way to achieve this. It is a way. and an ok way, but use better ways.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  Yeah, I realize its not the best way to accomplish it. It was more out of curiosity than something I wanted to put to use.  Makes sense.

Comment: And to be 100% honest that is what I wanted to hear. I want to make sure you know this isn't the best way and going another route will probably be better for practice! Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: [JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/hg9cvxop/16/)

It's all about the Callback Functions!

```
var amountScrolled = 50;
var loopRunning = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled){
        if(loopRunning === 0){
            animateSlide("0px",500); 
        }
    } else {
        if(loopRunning === 0){
            animateSlide("-400px",500);
        }
    }
});

function animateSlide(px, time){
    loopRunning = 1;
    $('#slide').stop().animate({marginLeft:px}, time, function(){
        loopRunning = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks! I will do more research on callback functions. For some reason it never occurred to me that the animation was being restarted every time I scrolled as obvious as it should have been. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer your question rather than provide advice on better ways to do it, I usually handle tasks like this by assigning a temporary class to denote that something is in the process of being animated. As somebody else said, the reason for the stuttering is because the scroll function is getting called multiple times, so you keep stopping and restarting the animation.

So you can try something like this ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3mk5dsk/)):

```
var amountScrolled = 50;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#slide').hasClass('sliding')) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled) {
        $('#slide').stop().addClass('sliding').animate({marginLeft:"0px"}, 500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('sliding');
        });
    } else {
        $('#slide').stop().addClass('sliding').animate({marginLeft: "-400px"}, 500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('sliding');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I never thought about it being called on multiple times. I still have a lot to learn it looks like. This looks great, thanks for the explanation and help!

Comment: Glad to help. I wanted to note, as well (since I don't know what your actual use case is for this), that if you use a callback function like this, you will probably want an extra check to see if you actually have to animate the thing. The reason being that regardless of whether the block has to be moved, the callback function will always fire off after the half second animation duration. In other words, that's half a second when the scroll function isn't getting beyond that initial return. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/n3mk5dsk/1/

Comment: Even better! That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I was trying to create a scroll-to-top button that slides in and out on a web page. I knew how to accomplish this using other methods, but I wanted to improve and expand on my jQuery knowlege. Thank you again! This is really helpful.